# How does one typically analyze a data set where the response variable has a discrete probability distribution?

Tags: regression, references, model

The response variable in my data set is what % of income households spent on a bunch of categories. So, the response variable is essentially a discrete probability distribution $[p_1, ..., p_k]$, where $k$ is the number of categories. Apart from this response, we have of course some independent variables, like the household's income, city, and so on.

Which model is typically used to analyze such a data set?

At the moment, I believe one can use a generalized linear model with the Dirichlet distribution. Would this work? Are there other methods?

Comment: Now in terms of your question: could you spell out more of what you mean by categories? In particular, quite different models may make sense depending on whether categories are ordered or not, for example. (In turn, I note that somebody else is more likely to answer. Categorical responses are not a specialism of mine.)

Comment: No, no order, just categories. The categories are like "Food", "transportation", etc. So if those were the only two categories, and the response is $[0.5, 0.5]$ for some household, then that household spent 50 % of their income on food, and the other half on transportation.